# sorting lines using arrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;


public class part2
{

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File f1 = new File("one.txt");
        File f2 = new File("two.txt");

        BufferedReader fr1 = null;
        BufferedReader fr2 = null;
        //BufferedReader fr3 = null;
        BufferedWriter fw = null;

        fr1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("one.txt"));
        fr2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("two.txt"));
        fw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("res.txt"));


        String line1 = fr1.readLine();
        String line2 = fr2.readLine();


        // merging two files into one
        while (line1 != null)
        {
            fw.write(line1);
            fw.newLine();

            line1 = fr1.readLine();

        }

        while (line2 != null)
        {
            fw.write(line2);
            fw.newLine();

            line2= fr2.readLine();

        }
        fw.close();

        // sorting a new file 

        BufferedReader fr3 = null;
        BufferedWriter fw1 = null;

        fw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("res1.txt"));
        fr3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("res.txt"));

        String line3 = fr3.readLine();

        ArrayList<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (line3 != null)
        {
            lineList.add(line3);
            line3 = fr3.readLine();
        }


        Collections.sort(lineList);

        for(int i=0; i<lineList.size(); i++)
        {
            fw1.write(lineList.get(i) + "\n");
            //line3 = fr3.readLine();

        }



      }
    }
```

I'm trying to merge two files together into "res.txt", and then sort the merged file alphabetically (and put the sorted lines in "res1.txt"). Everything works until the sorting, to be exact from the  while (line3 != null) line, i.e. it reads and merges two files, but doesn't sort them. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?  Posting code and saying "any ideas" isn't useful.  Does the program actually read data from the file?

Comment: Try closing your bufferedwriter to res.txt before trying to open it. Its possible the operating system isnt opening the file for reading because its open for writing

Comment: paddy, it works until the sorting, i.e. reads and merges two files, but doesn't do anything when I try to sort the lines. 
Jamil, I've done it with fw.close(); before sorting

Comment: Sorry must've missed that line. Can you see if your first call to String line3 = fr3.readline(); gives you anything?

Comment: If you debug, is lineList after Collections.sort?

Comment: if you asking if it works, then yes it prints the lines of both "one.txt" and "two.txt" merged if I ask it to

Comment: Taylor, what do you mean?

Comment: Please look up the "try with resources" idiom. Also I highly recommend you follow the java coding style guidelines (camel back, etc.).

Comment: Try a foreach loop instead. for(String s : linelist) fw1.write(s)

Comment: found the dumbest mistake on earth, thanks all for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close fw1 prior to exiting the program or it gets removed from memory before the content of the buffer is flushed.